# Javascript - Array of functions is this bad practices

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Can i do something like this, or it would be bad practices?

file1.js

```
export func1(param) {
 if (valid(param)) return 'valid';
 else return 'invalid'
}

export func2(param) {
 if (valid(param)) return 'valid';
 else return 'invalid'
}
```

file2.js

```
import { func1, func2 } from 'file1'

const list = [func1, func2]

function test(value){
    list.forEach((listValue) => {console.log(listValue(value));
 });
}
```

i have a lot of inputs in my project and i'm trying to minify amount of code for their validations

current implementation looks like

file1.js

```
export validate(type, param){
 switch(type){
   case TYPE1:
     if (valid){
      return 'valid';
     } else {
      return 'invalid';
     }
   case TYPE2:
     if (valid(param.rule)){
      return 'valid';
     } else {
      return 'invalid';
     }
   default:
     break;
}
```

file2.js

```
import validate from 'file1.js'

const object = {value: '', types: [
  {type: TYPE1, rule: SOME_RULE}
  {type: TYPE2, rule: SOME_OTHER_RULE}
]}

function validateObject(object) {
  object.types.forEach((type) => 
   {console.log(validate(type.type, {
             value: object.value,
             rule: type.rule}
   ));}
}
```

Comment: I don't see any particular problem with it assuming all functions takes the same amount of parameters and their type is compatible.

Comment: i'm kind of newbie, so i wondering can i do this. as i assume params can be object like {value: '', rule1: '', rule2: '' }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript a function is a first class citizen, a special kind of object to be precise, so it's perfectly good practice to have an array of functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think personally that it's a bad practice. Let's think about making a soup and you have some pots to fill.

```
var steps = [ addWater, addPotatoes, addSalt, stirContents, cook ];
var pots = [ small_pot, medium_pot, large_pot ];

// if you use a method list here: 
for(pot in pots)
    for(step in steps)
       steps[step].call(this, pots[pot]);

// if you don't use a method list:
for(pot in pots)
{
   addWater(pots[pot]);
   addPotatoes(pots[pot]);
   addSalt(pots[pot]);
   stirContents(pots[pot]);
   cook(pots[pot]);
}
```

if you have the same inputs for every step, does it make a difference? you can add another step to both methods.